# not able to add two rows in seperate lines in a fluid container in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want two rows in a container-fluid but both the rows keep getting wrapped up in one line which I don't want. I want the second row under the first one.
this is  my code

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row d-flex flex-row justify-content-center gx-5">
    <div data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="1500">
      <div class="col-sm col-md p-3">
        <a class="shadow btn1" href="#">Work</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-delay="1500">
      <div class="col-sm col-md p-3">
        <a class="shadow btn1" href="#">About</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="1500">
      <div class="col-sm col-md p-3">
        <a class="shadow btn1" href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row d-flex flex-row justify-content-center gx-5">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-6 p-3">
      <img class="w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/3000x1000/?nature,beaches">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-md p-3">
      213333333333
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[this IS HOW I WANT IT TO BE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKgtc.png)

Comment: And what about this is supposedly not working? https://jsfiddle.net/w4uz78mf/

Comment: can you be more explicit about what should be at each line?

Comment: @CBroe it works on jfiddle but not on my website. what shud i do?

Answer (score 0):

Remove d-flex and flex-row

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center gx-5">
    <div data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="1500">
      <div class="col-sm col-md p-3">
        <a class="shadow btn1" href="#">Work</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-delay="1500">
      <div class="col-sm col-md p-3">
        <a class="shadow btn1" href="#">About</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="1500">
      <div class="col-sm col-md p-3">
        <a class="shadow btn1" href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center gx-5">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-6 p-3">
      <img class="w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/3000x1000/?nature,beaches">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-md p-3">
      213333333333
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```